# Can this work as a dark-activated light circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, led, resistors, diodes

I am fairly new to electronics and have been tasked with the question of describing the behaviour of this circuit. I can see that the LED is supposed to switch on when it is dark, but I am struggling to calculate the voltage drop across the LDR and LED in parallel.

I understand that in a parallel circuit the current will take the path of least resistance, however I am struggling to factor in the resistance of the LED as I understand it will resist current until a large enough voltage is passed through it. However, the voltage across the parallel depends on the equivalent resistance of the parallel circuit which seems rather complex to calculate. I understand that if a standard bulb replaced the LED then we would have a good idea of its resistance within standard operating temperatures and so an equivalent resistance here could be calculated. I am starting to wonder if this LED set up will even work?

[image]

Comment: What is the resistance of the LDR in light and dark conditions?  Initially, ignore the LED and calculate the voltage across the LDR in both light and dark.

Comment: This has to be assumed. From literature values for a standard LDR, the resistance in light conditions would be roughly 1kΩ and 1MΩ in dark. Wouldn't the voltage across the LDR depend on the resistance of the fixed resistor though? Please note that this a purely theoretical circuit.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is YES, it can work as a dark-activated light.

The main thing you need to understand about LEDs (or diodes in general) is that they are non-linear devices, meaning their current changes greatly for very small changes in voltage across them, **further** meaning an LED has a working voltage of a narrow range. 
This also means that an LED will not turn on until a certain voltage is reached, and that voltage depends on its chemistry - a red LED usually turns on around 1.5-1.6V, a white LED around 2.4-2.6V.

So, you first need to figure out the resistor value assuming a voltage across the LED and the current through it. 
If a white LED needs about 2.5V to work, you calculate 5-2.5=2.5V across the resistor. 
Then you take the maximum current you will allow through the LED, say 10mA, and calculate the resistor value as 2.5V/0.01A=250Ω. 
However, if your LDR has about 1kΩ resistance under light, that would make it drop 10V (theoretically) and would never turn the LED off. 
So, we use a lower current limit which would cause significantly less than 2.5V across the LDR when it's fully lit and has its lowest resistance of 1kΩ (you could also use an LDR which has a lower resistance). 
With a 1kΩ LDR, you can't use more than 2mA, so the resistor would need to have about 5 times larger resistance, which can be from 1.2kΩ to 1.5kΩ. Larger R values will make sure the LED is turned off even at lower light levels, but will also make it less bright when fully on.

This design wastes energy, and it is only good for grasping some basic principles. A better design involves a transistor, which wastes far less energy while providing "sharper" turn on and off points.

Comment: Thankyou. So would I be right in saying that as the resistance of the LDR goes up in the dark, this resistance would be significantly higher than the resistance of the LED as it reaches its forward voltage meaning that almost of the 10mA of current is diverted to the LED. What I am struggling to understand is how the LED could stay off in moderate light, where the ldr is at a resistance of say 10kΩ, as this is still much higher than the resistance of the fixed resistor. At this resistance, how could you calculate the voltage drop across the LDR and LED?

Comment: there's a way to do that  - it uses logarythms and the temperature and other annoying details.  at a first approximation assume that the LED does nothing until it sees 2V and then with 2v conducts freely so it never sees more, then treat two resistors as a voltage divider ...

Comment: Okay i think I understand now. Thank you. When you say that the LED does nothing though, do you mean it does not conduct until it sees 2V? So when it 'does nothing' that is to say that all the current is going through the LDR?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the LED is basically off until it reaches a certain voltage, like about 2.2-2.4V for a white LED, so you may pretty much ignore it until it starts glowing at above 2V. Your problem can be solved by increasing the value of the R, or decreasing the resistance of the LDR so that you can use lower R values as well, and get higher LED current and brightness. As you can guess, this is an inefficient design. Sure, it uses fewer components, but it's wasting a lot of energy: half when LED is on, and then twice as much when it is off, or the same total power at both on and off.